# How to make output of phpunit without buffering (not about ob_cache)

Tags: php, phpunit

PHP Unittest, when executing tests, drawers neat dots for each test, and if there are a lot of tests, it does it in several lines, drawing the percentage of execution on each line. Something like that

```
Runtime:       PHP 7.3.31-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 with Xdebug 3.0.4
Configuration: /var/www/mobport/phpunit.xml.dist

...............................................................  63 / 109 ( 57%)
.............................................
```

And I saw how it works in the "online" mode, that is, the dots are drawn immediately after the execution of each test. The output is not buffered.

At the moment, my output is buffered and I wait 2 minutes and then immediately draw the entire screen with a description of the system, settings for all points and final errors, if any.

How can I disable this buffering?

Comment: The buffering isn't coming from PHPUnit. Are you viewing this output via a web page of a CI/CD service or something?

Comment: I saw how it works in the "online" mode in terminal after running:
php vendor/bin/phpunit --bootstrap tests/bootstrap.php --configuration phpunit.xml.dist tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be Bitrix. The Bitrix kernel actively uses ob_cache and does not close the caching layers until the end. We solved the problem like this:

```
while (ob_get_level()) {
    ob_end_clean();
}
```

Video screen: https://mpakfmtest.ru/video/unittest3.mp4